# CustomCell not displaying two message swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to display user message and the chatbot message which is stored as array. after testing the below code the chatbot message appears but not the user message. can anyone fix this problem.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customMessageCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.messages.text = messageArray[indexPath.row].userMessage
        cell.messages.text = messageArray[indexPath.row].sundayMessage
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(messageArray.count)
        return messageArray.count

    }
```

Comment: This will show only `messageArray[indexPath.row].sundayMessage`.

Comment: Please read your code carefully. `userMessage` and `sundayMessage` are assigned to the **same** label. The second  value overwrites the first.

Comment: you are setting both userMessage and chatbot message to same label . Check and add it properly to appropriate cells

Comment: You are overwriting on cell.messages Label. Thats why you can't see userMessage and sundayMessage

Comment: If you want to show both message in a cell then add another label in the cell and set `messageArray[indexPath.row].sundayMessage` to newly created label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You require some changes in your model in order to check the current message you have is of user type or bot type. Once you are able to figure it out then you can just use the following logic:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customMessageCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

           //this is the check you need to have
           if messageArray[indexPath.row].userType == "bot"{
            cell.messages.text = messageArray[indexPath.row].sundayMessage

           }else if messageArray[indexPath.row].userType == "user"{
            cell.messages.text = messageArray[indexPath.row].userMessage
           }
            return cell
     }
```

Comment: i used this code but after the chatbot replies the user message row is updated to chatbot message and another row with chatbot message is create        below is my updated code                       if updateTVC == true {
        cell.messages.text = messageArray[indexPath.row].userMessage
            updateTVC = false
        } else {
        cell.messages.text = messageArray[indexPath.row].sundayMessage
        }
        return cell

Comment: I think the issue now is due to the fact that the model you are using for checking is not being updated properly. After sending both the chat bot message and user message, the model should be updated and then only table should be reloaded.

Comment: when the user sends the message the table is reloaded and after it gets the message from chatbot the table is again reloaded. after which 1st message is replaced by chatbot message and another chatbot message is also displayed. and i have printed the model and it works fine

Comment: I still think there is some issue with the models/array of models you are using to pull the data from because here the above logic simple renders on the basis of that logic. Check that if you are toggling the updateTVC at the right time

Comment: it seems like the when the 2nd condition execute it executes multiple times. when i printed the return value if it is 3 then the indexpath of 2nd value is 0,1,2 . how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

The latter line here replaces the whole string set by the former:

```
cell.messages.text = messageArray[indexPath.row].userMessage
cell.messages.text = messageArray[indexPath.row].sundayMessage
```

If you want both messages to be in the `cell.messages` text, you could do this:

```
let message = messageArray[indexPath.row]
cell.messages.text = "user: " + message.userMessage + "\nsunday: " + message.sundayMessage
```